# How to properly deal with long key constraints(longer than 3072) in MySql?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I can see that there are similar questions and answers on SO regarding this problem.
I need to create a unique constraint on 7 columns together.

```
alter table ga_data_model add constraint uq_1234596 unique (portal_id,date,dimension,country,os,os_version,theme);
```

there has been various answers to use prefix keys to solve this issue. However, because of the nature of my data, simply using the first one or two character to create the index is dangerous as this might result in having duplicate results. So such a solution won't work for me:

```
alter table ga_data_model add constraint uq_1234596 unique (portal_id,date(2),dimension(2),country(1),os(2),os_version(1),theme(2));
```

I was thinking of creating a new column in my table that contains the calculated hash of these columns and I create my constraint on this one. But this means that every time I want to insert something into db, I need to first do a select for this column, calculated the hash for the new values, compare them and save/or not save. I think this is a bit too expensive, considering that I will be having a lot of write operations.

Has anyone had the same problem and have a better solution as I explained above?
Thanks!

Comment: Edit your question, and paste in the CREATE TABLE statement for your table. Also paste a few INSERT statements. It seems odd to me that these seven columns amount to 3kb of data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to insert something into db, I need to first do a select for this column, calculated the hash for the new values, compare them and save/or not save

No - you save it, and if you get a unique key violation then you already have the data. Also, implement the hash calculation as a table trigger - that way there's no backdoor for amending the data.